# MongoDB Performance of several $EQs vs $NE in an indexed table

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, mongodb-query, database

I have a large account table with `~550K` records. Each account
has a field named AccountState which was defined as one of the 
indices to that table.

AccountState represents one of the following states:

1. Active - 5000 records
2. ReadOnly - 20,000 records
3. Archived - 500,000 records
4. Quarantine - 10 records

Now I would like to fetch all accounts that are not marked as 'Archived' from the DB. Performance-wise, what would be the most efficient way of doing so?

The possibilities that came up to mind are:

1. $NE for "Archived"
2. A query with several $EQ "Or" conditions for all states that are not

   "Archived" (Active, ReadOnly, Quarantine).

Or maybe there's a better way to achieve best results?

Thanks,

Comment: ~550k is not extremely big, can't you just fire both the queries and see how long they take?

Comment: Consider discarding the "Archived" state and create a sparse index for the rest of states